# Change the language tag to mean human language?

Tags: discussion, tags

In tagging [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21447/what-is-the-difference-between-the-variant-language-dictionaries-in-os-x), I was surprised that the language tag was described as being for programming language rather than human language. However, of all the questions using the language tag, [only one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14663/two-macbook-pros-display-my-webpage-differently) is related to programming language. The rest all are related to human language.

Any objections to changing the meaning of the language tag to be human language?

Comment: That sounds pretty sensible. Tags should be defined as how they are used, not how they could be used, and clearly it is being used all for spoken language.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as you have done, I would simply remove the one oddball usage and standardize on what it seems to be used for in practice.

Comment: This is the beauty of tags - the site shapes what they mean here. Yes - the tag summary helps to define things for new people, but more importantly it shows what that tag means in the narrow focus of questions being asked here. The cooking site can have one meaning for brown and the web design site a very different and conflicting meaning.

Comment: tag wikis are also very important for this, particularly in light of http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/improved-tagging/

Comment: I wouldn't have even noticed if not for the new tag completion -- I think it's great.